# If I click first image view and picj image from the gallery or camera then selected image is set both image view

Tags: java, android

I have get two image view . If I click first image view and pick image from the gallery or camera then selected image is set both image view ...but my need is this image set only one image view and if I click second image view then pick image and this image is set only second image view

If first image view is click then open gallery or camera and pick image and this image set only first image view

Comment: you should edit the question and add your code

Comment: Please add your code for more information